# Total amount of time spent in specific time period across multiple days

Tags: excel, datetime, time, excel-formula, date-arithmetic

I have been having difficulty with the following problem. <del>I have the following excel spreadsheet: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dG2p1y4WZE3AK2ubO2I1C55Ky2pLF7-r)</del>

I need an Excel formula to calculate the total amount of time spent between a specific time period i.e `20:00` and `05:00`, between a **start date** and **end date** for example:

<sub>*(Rephrased for Clarity:)*</sub>

> **TIME SPAN:**
>    `Start_TimeStanmp`     `2018/04/04 00:12:53`
>    `End_TimeStamp`          `2018/04/16 13:24:04`
>
> **DAILY SHIFT:**
>    *`"Shift" Start`*      `20:00:00`
>    *`"Shift" End`*         `05:00:00`
>
> ### What are the total hours of TIME SPAN that fall into DAILY SHIFTS?

Comment: does the "specific time period" always cross midnight like that?

Comment: It does unfortunately which is why I am having difficulty, It is always from 20:00 to 05:00

Comment: What's wrong with subtracting the START_TIMESTAMP from the END_TIMESTAMP and formatting the result as `[hh]:mm:ss` ?

Comment: @jeeped ...because that doesn't count **only the hours that fall between 20:00 and 5:00**

Comment: It does if you include the date with the time.

Comment: how?  there are basically 2 stop periods and 2 start periods that need to be compared every day.  You're the 3rd or 4th person to miss that part of the question (other answers deleted)... I'm going to change the OP's formatting to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jeeped - my sample data? If you're referring to the times I included in my answer, that is just an example of how it's worked out.  It's not up to me to provide sample data, but I understood exactly what the OP meant.  However, I've edited the OP's example so hopefully it will be easier for others to understand.

Comment: @Jeeped - ah yes - I do that frequently, occasionally not realizing for days

Comment: Still the question is not completely clear. Do you have to take count of summer- and wintertime? And how to round the whole hours? Round up or round down?

Comment: @ffonz (and everyone!) - Although the OP hasn't responded, I'm quite confident that I'm clear on what he needs as I used to do a lot of similar calculations for staffing & resource usage -- I'm not sure what you mean about summer and rounding, etc, but if you look at the calculation example at the bottom of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955750/8112776), that shows how the OP's example would be calculated.   Think of it as combining two schedules (one a multi-day time frame, and one a daily pattern) and calculating the total overlapped hours.

Comment: @ffonz ...also, that being said I'm NOT saying I have the best solution - I was tired when I wrote that and I feel like there's a more efficient method of calculating it -- but the answer my method comes up with is correct (or at least, I'd bet on it).  So give 'er a shot.  But rounding is rounding like you would any time calculation.  (...AND note that the OP's mention of `DAILY SHIFT` was ***my*** rephrase of the question because everyone wasn't noticing the `20:00 to 05:00` part in a smaller font!)  It would be nice if OP returned to confirm some of this stuff for us.

Comment: @ashleedawg I agree with you. You feel more responsible for the question than the OP because of the effort making the question more clear. I am thinking of another solution that takes the shifting of summertime (aka daily saving time) into account. But it is a waste of time if the OP doesn't respond.

Comment: @ffonz Ah - I see what you're referring to now.  I recently tackled daylight savings myself too, frustrated with inconsistent results or complicated methods.  (It was a heck of a lot easier once I realized there was a clear pattern behind it, in North America anyway...  3rd Sunday of March; 1st Sunday of November; every year... why didn't anyone ever explain that to me before?!  I was using tables of dates, and API's and blah blah blah.  It's time for the world to get rid of DST anyhow!)

Comment: @ffonz Excel doesn't have any built-in functions to determine whether DST is in effect (and therefore what the timezone offset is) given, for example, dates in the future/past. Indeed you can call a [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx) from VBA, or various [external API's](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/)  but it's a convoluted, memory hogging process. I have a lot of situations where I need to convert past/future data from other time zones (usually UTC) to Local (usually but not always mine). I had to write my own solution.

Comment: @ashleedawg My wrong! My apologies. So better use UTC.

Comment: It's all stored as UTC but ultimately needs to be converted to Local Time (w/ DST) to make it human-friendly.  Humans should all just start using UTC for everything... it would only be weird for a while...  *"Son, remember it's your bedtime at 0530 and not a minute later!"*

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way but this UDF should do the trick:

```
Function hoursBetween(startDT As Date, stopDT As Date, timeStart As Date, timeStop As Date) As Single

    Dim dt As Date, thisStart As Date, thisStop As Date
    For dt = Int(startDT) To Int(stopDT) + IIf(timeStop < timeStart, -1, 0)

        thisStart = timeStart
        thisStop = timeStop

        If timeStart < timeStop Then
            Select Case dt
                Case Int(startDT) 'its the 1st day of the range
                    thisStart = IIf(startDT - Int(startDT) > timeStart Or (timeStart < timeStop), startDT - Int(startDT), timeStart)
                Case Int(stopDT) 'its the last day of the range
                    thisStop = IIf(stopDT - Int(stopDT) < timeStop, stopDT - Int(stopDT), timeStop)
            End Select
            Debug.Print dt & " : " & thisStart & " to " & thisStop
        Else
            'the day crosses midnight
            Select Case dt
                Case Int(startDT) 'its the 1st day of the range
                    thisStart = IIf(startDT - Int(startDT) > timeStart, timeStart, startDT - Int(startDT))
                Case Int(stopDT)  'its the last day of the range
                    thisStop = IIf(stopDT - Int(stopDT) > timeStop, timeStop, stopDT - Int(stopDT))
            End Select
        End If

        thisStart = thisStart + dt
        thisStop = thisStop + dt
        If thisStop < thisStart Then thisStop = thisStop + 1
        hoursBetween = hoursBetween + ((thisStop - thisStart) * 24)
        Debug.Print dt & " : " & thisStart & " to " & thisStop, "Day hrs: " & ((thisStop - thisStart) * 24)
    Next dt
End Function
```

To test it with your example:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print hoursBetween(#2018/04/04 00:12:53#, #2018/04/16 13:24:04#, #20:00#, #05:00#)
End Sub
```

Note that "not knowing" if the *shift time* will always cross midnight like in your example, required double the amount of code... (although there are likely ways to streamline it.)

---

```
04-04 : 04-04 12:12:53 to 04-04 05:00:00           Day hrs: 4.79
04-05 : 04-05 20:00:00 to 04-06 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-06 : 04-06 20:00:00 to 04-07 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-07 : 04-07 20:00:00 to 04-08 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-08 : 04-08 20:00:00 to 04-09 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-09 : 04-09 20:00:00 to 04-10 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-10 : 04-10 20:00:00 to 04-11 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-11 : 04-11 20:00:00 to 04-12 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-12 : 04-12 20:00:00 to 04-13 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-13 : 04-13 20:00:00 to 04-14 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-14 : 04-14 20:00:00 to 04-15 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
04-15 : 04-15 20:00:00 to 04-16 05:00:00           Day hrs: 9
                                                   Total: 103.7853
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier/non-VBA method as [ashleedawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955750/9290986) said would probably exist:  (I will use `A1` as the Start Date, and `B1` as the End Date)

The "tricky" part here is that each shift skips over midnight - to correct for this, I will subtract the Start Time (`Time(20,0,0)`) from **all** datetimes to zero-out.

### Step 1

Start with the "full days" count - so, "23rd to 25th" is "2 days" - and then multiply that by the "hours-per-day":  (The `MOD` is to automatically correct for whether or not the shift crosses midnight)

```
=(Int(B1-Time(20,0,0))-Int(A1-Time(20,0,0)))*Mod(1+Time(5,0,0)-Time(20,0,0),1)
```

### Step 2

Next, we need to trim any pre-start time from the first day.  Since we are aligning the start-time to "00:00" anyway, we can just `MAX` that against 0:  (To get *just* the time, we use `MOD(A1,1)`):

```
=-MAX(0, MOD(A1,1)-TIME(20,0,0))
```

### Step 3

Last, we need to trim any post-end time from the last day.  We will use `MIN` to take the earlier time as cut-off this time:

```
=+MIN(Mod(1+Time(5,0,0)-Time(20,0,0),1), MOD(B1-TIME(20,0,0),1))
```

### Add it up

Put all of that into one formula, and there you go:

```
=(INT(B1-TIME(20,0,0))-INT(A1-TIME(20,0,0)))*MOD(1+TIME(5,0,0)-TIME(20,0,0),1)-MAX(0, MOD(A1,1)-TIME(20,0,0))+MIN(MOD(1+TIME(5,0,0)-TIME(20,0,0),1), MOD(B1-TIME(20,0,0),1))
```

**{EDIT}** *You can change `TIME(20,0,0)` and `TIME(5,0,0)` to cell references that contain your shift start/end times.  The code should work so long as the shifts are under 24-hours*